# isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returning 9

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have the following code in my app to initiate Map View

```
private boolean servicesOk() {
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,
                this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connect Connect to Maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
    return false;
}
```

But on the check the `isAvailable` has the value `9`, moreover in `LogCat` its continously repeating message: `Google Play services is invalid. Cannot recover.`

Can anyone please tell me, what mistake Am I making?

Comment: Are you running this on the emulator?

Comment: yes.. does it effects?

Comment: Make sure that you're running it on Google API's API Level 18, not Android 4.3 (or similarly 4.2 & API level 17 , and so on.)

Comment: how can i change that? in AVD manager i only have one option `Android 4.3 - API Level 18` can you please help in this?

Comment: Go to SDK Manager.exe (same location as AVD manager), and under Android 4.3 (API Level 18) click the checkbox next to Google APIs, and then click the button near the bottom with Install 1 Package

Comment: Did that help you? If not, I can try and help you some more.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: Happens to me from time to time on a Samsung Galaxy 6 device where I know for sure that Google Play service is the official release. I'm unable to determine why this is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SERVICE_INVALID) 9 is an invalid/inauthentic install of google play services.

Have you made sure you downloaded and updated gps from the play store?