# GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returns SERVICE_INVALID on a stock Samsung Galaxy S6 phone

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm a developer for a company with several apps. We are using `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` to check if the device has Google Play services installed regularly on app startup. We've noticed that from time to time - on Two Samsung Galaxy 6 devices we get `SERVICE_INVALID` (9) response from the `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` (which means "The version of the Google Play services installed on this device is not authentic.").

We are using a old Google Play services lib (3.2.65) due to compatibility reasons (I know , we should upgrade ASAP, we are working on it).

We are talking about Stock Android devices, fully updated, that no one changed in any way. We display a msg to the user in case isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returns a value other than success, which causes some confusion when it returns SERVICE_INVALID because the app receives Gcm msgs although it's "invalid".

Any ideas?

BTW - this is NOT a duplicate of [isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returning 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083447/isgoogleplayservicesavailable-returning-9)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it's not too late to answer ;-)

I've had experience working with Samsung devices in the past. Iv'e also encountered this code returning from Google play lib. Iv'e dealt with it in two ways :

1. Check several times the status of Google play in times you get a "bad" code like SERVICE_INVALID. You can wait for several seconds before checking again.
2. In case your check fails let's say after 3 attempts - mark the relevant functionality that depends on Google Play lib as inactive and check once every 30-60 seconds if your function to check Google Play returns a valid value.

You must remember that Google play is a vast collection of services that sometimes is not able to process requests from apps due to internal work or some internal state. In almost all cases it will become fully functional again within seconds or minutes.

good luck!

Comment: we've implemented something along the lines of what you described, thanks.