# IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable SERVICE_INVALID

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I have a Xamarin application that should display a google map control. I try to make it works in Android but I have some errors.

To me, the error seems related to the Google Play Service, so I try to check the status but I got an error message "SERVICE_INVALID".

With the emulator, it works when I use Nougat 7.1 by example, but not the version 9 ...

I use the following code:

```
public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable()
    {
        // Verifies that Google Play services is installed and enabled on this device, and
        // that the version installed on this device is no older than the one required by this client.
        var resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
        {
            if (GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsUserResolvableError(resultCode))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorString(resultCode));
                //Log.Debug(TAG, GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorString(resultCode));
            }
            else
            {
                //Log.Debug(TAG, "This device is not supported");
                Finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        //Log.Debug(TAG, "Google Play Services is available.");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any specific error messages??? If so, please edit your post and copy/paste the error messages into it.

Comment: Are Google Play Services available on that device?

Comment: @paulsm4 yes, the message is already in the description, the error message is "SERVICE_INVALID" ... but I don't know what it mean! I'm on the emulator... it work with Nougat 7.x but not with version > 8.x

Comment: @Christian yes Google Play services are installed, version 21.15.15

Comment: It might be a timing issue.  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55917167/421195